# Is there a way to erase string completely in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I want to erase confidential string like password, creditcard number from memory.

In C#, there is a class named SecureString.

But In VB6, I didn't find any solution.

Is there a way to erase string completely from memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `SecureString` is encrypted while at rest which is more than just providing a way to prevent it remaining in memory.

> Is there a way to erase string completely from memory?

Yes, you need to modify the string in-situ and overwrite its contents.

You can do this using `mid$()` in LHS mode:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Len(secret)
    Mid$(secret, i, 1) = "0"
Next
```

Or with the `ZeroMemory` or `CopyMemory` API:

```
ZeroMemory ByVal StrPtr(secret), LenB(secret)
...
CopyMemory ByVal StrPtr(secret), ByVal StrPtr(String$(Len(secret), "0")), LenB(secret)
```

For encryption you could implement the [DPAPI `CryptProtectData` API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Windows/desktop/aa380261(v=vs.85).aspx) (which is what `SecureString` is based on).